# call self invoking function from outside body function

Tags: javascript

So i have the following code:

```
(function init_chart(){
    // body function
})();
```

it's working as expected. but when i tried to call the `init_chart()` from outside the function, console said it is undefined. then i tried to add the following line inside `init_chart()` function:

```
window['init_chart'] = this;
```

now console said init_chart is not a function.

Comment: Put `window.init_chart = init_chart;` inside the function.

Comment: `this` actually refer to the window object (in your case)

Comment: What made you think that `this` refers to the function? `this` never refers to the function itself, unless you explicitly set it so.

Comment: awesome thanks. jquery "told" me so :D...it's my fault, I have to learn more about JS. thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a *named function expression* function, so basically the function is not defined on the global scope. The easiest way to get around it is to do the following:

```
function init_chart(){
    // body function
};
init_chart();
```

Comment: "Named anonymous function" is kind of an oxymoron. Surely you mean "named function expression", right? ;)

Comment: @Scimonster it's way too early in the morning haha